# Refresh core plot axis labeling while keeping the range the same

Tags: core-plot

How do I trigger the refresh of the core plot axis labels while keeping the range the same?

I tried `CPTAxis relabel`, `CPTAxis setNeedsRelabel`, `CPTAxis setNeedsDisplay`, resetting the axis range (to the same range), reloading complete graph data. Nothing helps, the axis is only going to be updated on touch events or if I change the axis range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-setNeedsRelabel` will refresh the labels. You normally don't need to call this method. Changing any of the labeling properties should trigger the label refresh automatically.